# Equivalent in JavaScript to DateTime.Ticks

Tags: javascript, c#

Is there anything in JavaScript similar to `DateTime.Ticks` in C#?

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second.

([DateTime.Ticks on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: do you mean Ticks?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: Then you can use new Date().getTime() which returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 and which you should be able to convert to .net ticks

Comment: I have made (Date().getTime() )this already but then  i can't convert it into Ticks

Comment: do you know  how does Ticks  work in javasscript?

Comment: AFAIK there's no Ticks in JS's Date, so you have to use getTime and do the math knowing that .net ticks represent the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

Comment: Reworded the question to express the core problem

Comment: Why do you need this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i want to invoke service which is made in C#  but i need to invoke it through nifi and i have to write appropriate javasscript code to generate similar date(in C# it is DateTime.picks) and pass it as an argument later

Comment: Why don't you just send a serialized DateTime?

Comment: because i invoke service by remote url in nifi   processor i can't use any language(for writing code) except:ecmascript,puthon,jyton,lua,groovy

Comment: as i guess did you mean writing something like service client under serialization or i misunderstood it?

Comment: ECMAScript has serialization... it's called "JSON"

Answer (score 2):

I  have  found  result, someone has  already posted on "stackoverflow" year ago and it perfectly fits my solution

```
var result1=(date1.getTime()*10000)+621355968000000000; 
var result2=(date2.getTime()*10000)+621355968000000000;
```